# How much regularization to add to make SVD stable?

Tags: numerical-analysis, stability, svd, intel-mkl, numerical-limitations

I've been using Intel MKL's SVD (`dgesvd` through SciPy) and noticed that results are are significantly different when I change precision between `float32` and `float64` when my matrix is badly conditioned/not full rank. Is there a guide on the minimum amount of regularization I should add to make results insensitive to `float32`->`float64` change?

In particular, doing $A=UDV^{T}$, I see that $L_\infty$ norm of $V^{T}X$ moves by about 1 when I change precision between `float32` and `float64`. $L_2$ norm of $A$ is $10^5$ and it has about 200 zero eigenvalues out of 784 total.

Doing SVD on $\lambda I + A$ with $\lambda=10^{-3}$ made the difference vanish.

Comment: What is the size $N$ of an $N\times N$ matrix $A$ for that example (is it even a square matrix)? 200 zero eigenvalues or singular values? A Frobenius norm $||A||_\text{F}$ for a representative example would be also helpful.

Comment: In this case 784 x 784 matrix, but I'm more interested in general technique to find good value of lambda

Comment: So, is the difference in $V$ only in the last columns corresponding to the zero singular values?

Comment: If there are several equal singular values, the svd is not unique. In your example, I guess that the problem comes from the multiple zero singular values and that a different precision leads to a different choice of the basis for the respective singular space. I do not know why that does change when you regularize...

Comment: ...what is $X$?

Comment: @Dirk It changes simply because there aren't multiple singular values anymore, I guess.

Comment: (Indeed, note that adding a multiple of $I$ does not change singular values predictably -- unlike eigenvalues.)

Comment: Would you know of $A \ x$ similar to yours on the web, to look at ? Thanks

Comment: Yup, here's a code to download/render into numpy the matrix I was looking at -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/svd_test.py#L27

Comment: Fwiw, a plot of the eigenvalues looks much like that of random correlation matrices.
See e.g. [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87032/eigenvalues-of-correlation-matrices-exhibit-exponential-decay)
on stats.stack .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question has a great answer, here's 
a rule of thumb for small singular values, with a plot.

> If a singular value is nonzero but very small,
>   you should define its reciprocal to be zero,
>   since its apparent value is probably an artifact of roundoff error, not a meaningful number.
>   A plausible answer to the question "how small is small ?"
>   is to edit in this fashion all singular values whose ratio to the largest
>   is less than $N$ times the machine precision $\epsilon$ .

$\qquad$ — [Numerical Recipes p. 795](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=795)

Added: the following couple of lines calculate this rule-of-thumb.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds  # sparse, dense or LinOp

#...............................................................................
def howsmall( A, singmax=None ):
    """ singular values < N float_eps sing_max  may be iffy, questionable
        "How small is small ?"
        [Numerical Recipes p. 795](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=795)
    """
        # print "%d singular values are small, iffy" % (sing < howsmall(A)).sum()
        # small |eigenvalues| too ?
    if singmax is None:
        singmax = svds( A, 1, return_singular_vectors=False )[0]  # v0=random

    return max( A.shape ) * np.finfo( A.dtype ).eps * singmax
```

---

The Hilbert matrix seems to be widely used as a test case for roundoff error:

[image]

Here low-order bits in the mantissas of the Hilbert matrix are zeroed,
`A.astype(np.float__).astype(np.float64)`,
then `np.linalg.svd` is run in `float64`.
(Results with `svd` all `float32` are about the same.)

Simply truncating to `float32` might even be useful for denoising high-dimensional data,
e.g. for train / test classification.

Real test cases would be welcome.

Comment: btw, scipy seems to add a factor of 1e3 for float32 and 1e6 for float64, curious where these came from

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov, `numpy` and `scipy.linalg.svd` call LAPACK
[gesdd](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d4/dca/group__real_g_esing.html),
see parameter `JOBR` in `dgejsv`:
"Specifies the RANGE for the singular values. Issues the licence to
set to zero small positive singular values if they are outside ..."
(`scipy.sparse.linalg.svds` wraps ARPACK
and has a parameter `tol`, Tolerance for singular values.)

Answer (score 13):

The singular value decomposition for a symmetric matrix $A=A^{T}$
is one and the same as its canonical eigendecomposition (i.e. with an orthonormal matrix-of-eigenvectors), while the
same thing for a nonsymmetric matrix $M=U \Sigma V^T$ is just the canonical eigenvalue
decomposition for the symmetric matrix 
$$
H=\begin{bmatrix}0 & M\\
M^{T} & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}U & 0\\
0 & V
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & \Sigma\\
\Sigma & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}U & 0\\
0 & V
\end{bmatrix}^{T}
$$
Hence, without loss of generality, let us consider a closely related
question: **If two symmetric matrices are approximately the
same, then should we expect their canonical eigendecompositions to also be approximately
the same?**

The answer is a surprising no. Let $\epsilon>0$ be small, and consider the two matrices
$$
A_{\epsilon}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \epsilon\\
\epsilon & 1
\end{bmatrix}=V\Lambda_{\epsilon}V^{T},\qquad B_{\epsilon}=\begin{bmatrix}1+\epsilon & 0\\
0 & 1-\epsilon
\end{bmatrix}=U\Lambda_{\epsilon}U^{T}
$$
both of which have eigenvalues $\Lambda_{\epsilon}=\mathrm{diag}(1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon)$,
but whose eigenvectors are
$$
V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix},\qquad U=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
While the matrices $A_{\epsilon} \approx B_{\epsilon}$ are approximately the same, their matrix-of-eigenvectors $V$ and $U$ are very different. Indeed, since the eigendecompositions are unique for $\epsilon>0$, there really exists no choice of $U,V$ such that $U\approx V$

Now, applying this insight back to the SVD under finite precision,
let us write $M_{0}=U_{0}\Sigma_{0}V_{0}^{T}$ as your matrix in `float64`
precision, and $M_{\epsilon}=U_{\epsilon}\Sigma_{\epsilon}V_{\epsilon}^{T}$
as the same matrix in `float32` precision. If we assume that the SVDs
themselves are exact, then the singular values $\Sigma_{0},\Sigma_{\epsilon}$
must differ by no more than a small constant factor of $\epsilon\approx10^{-7}$,
but the singular vectors $U_{0},U_{\epsilon}$ and $V_{0},V_{\epsilon}$
can differ by an arbitrarily large quantity. **Hence, as shown, there is no way to make the SVD "stable" in the sense of the singular vectors.**

Comment: Is this example from: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/markiwen/Teaching/MTH995/Papers/SVD_Stewart.pdf ?

Comment: That's a great reference. I don't know, I learnt this particular example many years ago in math class :-)